# How to trim and convert a string to integer?

Tags: c#, winforms, string, integer

how could I trim and convert a string as following:

```
string abc = "15k34"
int x = first two characters of abc // should be 15
but if abc begins with "0"
for example - string abc = "05k34"
int x = first two characters of abc // should be 5
```

Comment: Hint to simplify problem: `int.Parse("15") -> 15`, `int.Parse("05") -> 5`, `int.Parse("15k34") -> kaboom!` So, then "how to get first two letters" (which are presumably digits)? Well, what has been tried? (I am voting to close as Too Localized. Try things. Then find out why they didn't work or how they could be done better.)

Comment: string abc vary. next time is "09b23" for example. but first two chars are allways digits

Comment: Look at my first comment. `int.Parse("09") -> ???` So, how to get the "09" bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string abc = "15k34";
int x = 0;
//abc = "05k34";
int val;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(abc) && abc.Length > 1)
{
    bool isNum = int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, 2), out val);
    if (isNum)
    {
        x = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with following code:

```
            string str = "15k34";
            int val;
            if (str.Length>1)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, 2), out val))
                {
                    //val contains the integer value
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think from the pseudocode you will typically have numbers with 'k' in them representing thousands.

So...

```
string abc = "15k34";
string[] numbers = abc.Split('k');  //This will return a array { "15", "34" }
int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]);
```

If the string was "05k34"  the value of myInt would be 5 then.

documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx